# Calculating the average value of data in multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal, command

I know that the phrasing of the above question is pretty unclear but Ill do my best to explain. I have a set of data consisting of different hotel id values and a set of ratings for each respective hotel. This is the code I have right now:

```
cd "$1" || exit 1

grep "<Overall>" hotel_*.dat | sed 's/\.dat:<Overall>/ /'
```

(The code basically extracts the data from the files and outputs them in a neater format)

This is the output of the code:
[terminal output sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT6qB.png)

As you can see in the image my data consists of two columns. What I am trying to do is take the average of the data in column 2 for each hotel id, so basically get an output of: (hotel id) (average). Each hotel id should have its own average value.

What I tried doing was:

```
cd "$1" || exit 1

grep "<Overall>" hotel_*.dat | sed 's/\.dat:<Overall>/ /' | awk '{SUM+= $2} END {print SUM/NR}'
```

This takes the average of all the data and just outputs a number instead of an average for each hotel id in the format (hotel id) (average).

I hope my explanation suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` to aggregate as shown below:

```
$ cat file.txt
hotel_1 10
hotel_2 15
hotel_1 5

$ awk '{sum[$1] += $2; counts[$1]++;} END {for (i in sum) print i, sum[i]/counts[i];}'  file.txt
hotel_1 7.5
hotel_2 15
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! If I wanted to then sort this data using the sort command what is an easy way to do that?

Comment: Many ways, one way pipe(|) to `sort -nrk2`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: One last clarification, how can I make the output have 2 decimal places? I tried using printf but it changes the output format.

Comment: You can use printf in awk ; something like the one shown in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647798/how-to-restrict-the-decimal-places-in-awk-without-rounding-off)